# Conditionals - Ansible Junos

Tags: ansible, junos-automation

So this is conditionals on Ansible:

```
- debug:
        var: x
      when: x is not defined
```

Is there anyway to apply conditionals for junos_commands?
Like:

```
  tasks:
    - name: Show logs
      junos_command:
        commands:
        - show interfaces
      when: apply this condition
```

Comment: You can apply conditions to any task.  What condition in particular are you looking to use? Have you tried? What happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use when with junos_command but you need to apply conditions to the when statement. For example:

```
yum:
  name: iotop
  state: present
when: ansible_os_family == "RedHat"
```

This will install iotop only if system is a RedHat family. You can also apply conditions from scripts or tasks that were run before and you have registered there result. More information can be find here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html